# Tools to generate a database diagram/ER diagram from existing Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, reverse-engineering, documentation-generation, er-diagram

Looking for tools (windows platform) to genereate ER diagram (or similar) from an existing Oracle database.
Any good tools out there that are free to use or low cost?

Comment: Try using Dataedo http://dataedo.com - data dictionary and ERD generator for existing Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL databases. Enables documenting missing FKs, UKs, grouping into modules, pasting images and more.

Comment: There is a built-in [Oracle database designer](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/oracle-database-diagram.html) in dbForge Studio. Check out a free 30-day trial for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I few years ago, I used Data Architect, part of Power Designer from Sybase.  It's a little pricy, but it's excellent.  And it makes a fine distinction between the physical (SQL) model of data and the ER model of data.  It keeps both models side by side.

If you are not too concerned about the difference between SQL and ER, and you just want a diagram, here's something I did once when I needed a diagram in a big hurry.

Crank up MS Access with a new empty database.   Set up table links to all the tables in the schema, or just the ones you want to diagram.  Use the "Relationships" tool in Access to create lines between the foreign keys and the primary keys they refer to. Classify these relationships as to many-to-many or many-to-one.

In the Access relationships view, move the boxes around until the diagram is pretty.  Print.

Answer (score 23):

Try out [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html). 
It is from oracle and is going to be part of actual oracle installation from 11g onwards. It has a [separate build modeler tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) to engineer or re-engineer an ER model.

Other tool that may be useful that will help you more than just genereate ER diagram is [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: To use Oracle SQL Developer you need to connect to the database in question, export the DDL and then import the DDL with file -> data modeler -> import -> DDL File

Comment: @mmrobins can ScemaSpy generate ERD from DDL ?

Comment: @Jazzepi This is not correct. You open the `Data Modeler` tool, you go to `File` then to `Import` then to `Data Dictionary`and then from there you can connect to a database and have the tool generate the ERD for you.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Quite possibly. This answer was given 4 years ago.

Comment: What @Jazzepi said worked for me, since I already have a database created with data populated

Answer (score 7):

[SQL Developer](http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/) is awesome. Supports all the databases and perfect for reverse engineering. It free and Java.

Its Free unlike other solutions listed above and it works, I just used it to reverse engineer a Postgres db!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use VISIO with an ODBC data source (oracle plugin) to generate ER diagrams - works well. From VISIO (Database Model Diagram, Reverse Engineer, select ODBC data source, username/password, select tables, generate).

Comment: I recommend using the OLE DB data source.

Comment: This feature is not longer present as of Visio 2013. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2259709)

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html). It's free, and seems to have many good features if you're willing to research it more in depth.

Answer (score 2):

Power Architect is a GPL data modelling tool.
See more [here](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect)

Answer (score 2):

TOAD professional now includes their data-modeling tool.

Answer (score 1):

We use Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems. It's expensive but they do a trial version so you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

[SchemaCrawler for Oracle](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a command-line tool that can generate database diagrams from an Oracle database. You can exclude tables and columns from the diagram using regular expressions. It is free and open-source.

Comment: How? I was going through spring,velocity example provided by you ..but didint got any API which can generate ER diagram..InputStream generateERDiagram(Java connection object)?