# Oracle: Extract Graphical Database Representation

Tags: database, oracle

How can I extract (reverse engineering) a graphical (schema) representation of an Oracle database (tables and their relationships; with colums and datatypes....). Are there (free) tools, which can do this?

I think the Oracle SQL Developer has no such feature...

Comment: Probably more on-topic here: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: better discussed at [this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091599/tools-to-generate-a-database-diagram-er-diagram-from-existing-oracle-database)

Answer (score 3):

There is a related Oracle tool, SQL Developer Data Modeler which does reverse engineering and it is free.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sql Developer does this (check the SQL Modeller option) and lots lots more. An amazingly good tool !

Answer (score 1):

For a free tool I recommend schema spy, http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/.
It needs Java Runtime.
Look to http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html to see diagrams it generate.

This tool is also more suitable to automatic build scripts.

simple usage with oracle hr template is given below.

```
SET JDBC_ORACLE_JAR=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
SET CONNECTION_USERNAME=hr
SET CONNECTION_PASSWORD=hr
SET TNS_DATABASE_NAME=orcl
SET SCHEMA_NAME=HR
SET TABLE_NAME='EMP'
SET OUTPUT_NAME=HR_EMP

java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -dp %JDBC_ORACLE_JAR% -db %TNS_DATABASE_NAME% -o     schemaOutput%OUTPUT_NAME% -u %CONNECTION_USERNAME% -p %CONNECTION_PASSWORD% -i %TABLE_NAME%.* -schemas %SCHEMA_NAME% -hq -noviews -loglevel severe

java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -dp %JDBC_ORACLE_JAR% -db %TNS_DATABASE_NAME% -o     schemaOutput%OUTPUT_NAME% -u %CONNECTION_USERNAME% -p %CONNECTION_PASSWORD%  -schemas %SCHEMA_NAME% -hq -noviews -loglevel severe
```

First one will give you diagram with tables starting with EMP . 
Second one will give you diagram with all tables in hr schema .

Answer (score 0):

[Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) is an awesome PHP single file that should be able to do what you request. I tried only with MySQL, but Oracle it's supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any free tools: 
[MS Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/visio-edition-comparison-FX101838162.aspx) can reverse engineer (professional/Premium)
[TOAD](http://www.quest.com/landing/?ID=1485&s_kwcid=TC%7C23773%7C%7Bkeyword%7D%7C%7Bplacement%7D%7C%7Bifcontent%3aC%7D%7Bifsearch%3aS%7D%7Bifmobile%3aM%7D%7C%7Bmatchtype%7D%7C%7Bcreative%7D&gclid=CPu4jMmUuawCFSwZQgoddnaVeA&s_kwcid=TC%7C23773%7Coracle%20toad%7C%7CS%7Ce%7C5491128806) an expensive tool but well worth it IMO