# tool to generate DB relation overview from DB schema

Tags: database, eclipse, oracle, netbeans

I am looking for eclipse plugin or a open source free tool that can connect to oracle DB and
can create a mapping diagram of DB.i need graphical view showing tables relations ,primary key , foreign key constraints

For my sql SQL work bench does the job.What about oracle?

Is there any such tool available?

I know that netbeans hibernate plugin can generate beans corresponding to db tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Extract Graphical Database Representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140387/oracle-extract-graphical-database-representation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into [SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).  You should be able to reverse engineer an ER diagram.