# Oracle DB and a way to find which tables are linked to each other

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dictionary, database-schema

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to generate a database diagram/ER diagram from existing Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091599/tools-to-generate-a-database-diagram-er-diagram-from-existing-oracle-database)

I am working with a large scale DB. I am using SQL Developer to access the Oracle DB.
I have a high number of tables and schemas, and the tables are related to each other in some way. i.e. fields in table A exist in B as well so on...

I have heard there is a way to find out how they are all linked and produce a graph or a tree/list.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, you can query user_constraints/all_constraints/dba_constraints to produce a list of the foreign key relationships defined between tables. That can be formatted to be input to a number of graphing programs that will produce a directed graph of the relationships. I've used graphviz for this because at the simplest level you only need to output text along the lines of:

```
table1 -> table2
table2 -> table2
table2 -> table3
```

You can build on this to define the nodes as "records" to add more information about the tables.

Advantages: Completely free, much better automatic layout than ER tools
Disadvantages: Needs a bit of coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Oracle Data Modeller](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html). You can generate ER diagram from your existing database schema.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will tr it. However, I do remember an old collegue did a more basic query or script somehow. Thanks though

Comment: @sponger: if you need a query, you can try user_constraints/all_constraints/dba_constraints as David Aldridge sugessted.